# canLaunch is not launching URL in ios.But works fine in Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-debug, flutter-devtools

I am using `canLaunchUrl` to launch a UPI payment URL. This is working fine in Android but does not work in iOS. In iOS, they are not launching the URL instead they are moving to the else case and showing the toast message that we gave in the code. The UPI Url does not have any problem as we checked it separately. Moreover, `canLaunchUrl` works as it launches the phone number and email. Please help me to solve this problem.

Since `canLaunch` is deprecated I used `canLaunchUrl` and updated url_launcher to the latest version. But this too didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you add info.plist according to : https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: Do you mean under "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes"?

Comment: Yupp.......@Geethu

Comment: Can you add your LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The following code is present inside my Info.plist file.   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>itms-beta</string>
  <string>itms</string>
 </array>

Comment: Now it is automatically launching WhatsApp only while pressing the button. But I gave gpay in the list.<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>sms</string>
  <string>tel</string>
  <string>https</string>
  <string>http</string>
  <string>freecharge</string>
        <string>gpay</string>
        <string>in.fampay.app</string>
        <string>lotza</string>
        <string>mobikwik</string>
        <string>paytm</string>
        <string>phonepe</string>
        <string>upi</string>
        <string>upibillpay</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>

Comment: Does anyone know how to add the URLs scheme of phonepe and googlepay in Info.plist file?.Please share the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can launchUrl for example open map with URL from [launch_url](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package:

```
Future<void> _launchUrl({double? originLat, double? originLng}) async {
        String url = Uri.encodeFull(
            'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=23.070907724512406,72.51759912698715');
    
        if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), webViewConfiguration: const WebViewConfiguration(enableJavaScript: true));
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }
```

And put following into your `info.plist` file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>googlechromes</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>phonepe</string>
        <string>googlepay</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for adding URL schema of googlepay and phonepe in info.plist file.

Comment: Thank you, mam. Earlier I gave phonepe like this. But it didn't work.  Can you please tell me how to invoke a upi URL using canLaunchUrl().